# Install4j - how to exit when "insufficient disk space"

Tags: install4j

I use the installation components screen, and I have selected the option for `insufficient disk space warning`.  This works - I get a warning when there's not enough disk space, and the user is presented with a prompt along the lines of `continue y/n`...

The thing I can't figure out is how to exit the installer when they select `n`.  As it stands, when there's not enough disk space, and the user selects `n` (to "not continue"), the installer loops back to the installation components selection again, and cycles through the warning again - basically an endless cycle.

There's no "quit on failure" option for the screen, so how do I cancel the install when the user elects to `not continue` since there's not enough disk space?

Thanks....

Comment: it's been a week.  Any response from EJ Tech?  Is it being looked at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to insert code there, the loop goes back so you can select another installation directory with more space. I have created an issue so that canceling will be added as an option in console mode.

To check this condition beforehand, compare

```
SystemInfo.getFreeDiskSpace(context.getInstallationDirectory())
```

with

```
com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ContentInstaller.
    getInstance().getMinSize() * 1.1
```

(the above is not in the public API)

You can do that in a run script action that is guarded with `Util.isConsole()`. Returing false and setting the failure strategy property of the action to "Quit on failure" will exit the installer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There isn't always another partition available with more space, so sometimes you need to quit the app and go free some space.  Appreciate the info.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is "getMinSize" computing the "required space"?  Our app seems to require much more space than is being reported by that method.  I assume that it's because part of our install process is installing other packages (IE: mysql), and since they're packaged as a tar.gz file, i4j doesn't know their expanded space requirements.

Comment: Thanks - is it taking a "worst case scenario" from the choices in the installation type and components (since different "installation types" and components have different file requirements)?  The reason I ask is that when the install location is chosen, the user hasn't yet chosen the install type or optional components...  Wondering if I need to switch that around....

Comment: It uses the selected installation components that are selected at the time of the call. In that case of the Installation location screen, this is the default selection.